# keras lstm input shape error pleas help :(

Tags: keras, lstm

hi i`m trying to create lstm for predict value :(

but my limitation of understand for using keras dimension i think

i need help

my code belows

---

[train_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqnit.png)

```
train = train.to_numpy()
train = train.reshape(train.shape[0], 1, train.shape[2])
target_load = target_load.iloc[:].values

np.shape(train), np.shape(target_load)
```

[dataShapes for train and answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsiO9.png)

```
from keras import optimizers
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, LSTM, Bidirectional, Dropout

xInput = Input(shape=(1,7))
xLstm_1 = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(xInput) 
xLstm_1 = Dropout(0.2)(xLstm_1)
xLstm_2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(128))(xLstm_1)
xOutput = Dense(1)(xLstm_2)

ada = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)

model = Model(train, target_load)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=ada)

model.summary()
```

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1HQ0.png)

Comment: This has nothing to do with input shapes, you should pass symbolic tensors to build a model, like mode = Model(xInput, xOutput)

Answer (score 0):

Check TensorFlow's API: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model

Model objects must be instantiated using symbolic tensors:

```
tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)`
```

In your case that is:

```
model = Model(inputs = xInput, outputs = xOutput)
```